# How to get HTML content of a DIV in PHP

Tags: php, html, parsing, preg-match, simple-html-dom

I need to get the HTML content of a DIV from the URL. I've already try to get the content of the div with preg_match() and simple_html_dom but I've only get the plain text.

Example with simple_html_dom :

```
$html = file_get_html('http://webpage.tld');
$code = $html->find('#mydiv', 0);
var_dump($code->plaintext);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of `$code->plaintext` use `$code->outertext`